# Expected number of consecutive heads in 10 coin tosses

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value

I am having trouble formulating the exact recursive relation for [this](https://brainstellar.com/puzzles/118) problem. The problem statement is `A coin is tossed 10 times and the output written as a string. What is the expected number of HH? Note that in HHH, number of HH = 2. (eg: expected number of HH in 2 tosses is 0.25, 3 tosses is 0.5)`

The recursive relation I came up with is $$ E(10) = \frac{1}{2}E(9) + \frac{1}{4}E(8) + \frac{1}{4}(E(9)+1) $$
My reasoning behind this is: The last toss is T with a probability of 1/2, so we'll have to only look for no of consecutive heads in the first 9 tosses, but if the last toss is H, then it matters what the second last toss was, it we have TH situation, then the no of consecutive heads is the same as in first 8 tosses, but if we have the last two tosses as HH, then we have no of consecutive heads as one more than the no of heads in first 9 tosses.

The solution given states the following recursive relation $$ E(10) = \frac{1}{2}E(9) + \frac{1}{4} E(9) + \frac{1}{4}(E(9)+1) $$
So basically, the difference is in the second term of the recursive relation. I am not able to wrap my head around this solution, is there a fundamental error in my understanding?

Comment: Why use a recursion?  Indicator variables are much more efficient. For $n$ tosses, there are $n-1$ places an $HH$ block could start so the answer is $E_n=\frac {n-1}4$.  if you are counting $k$ consecutive Heads the answer would be $\frac {n-k+1}{2^k}$

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to go to $(n-2)$th  toss in your recurrence relation. Here is how you would want to look at it -

Say we have $ \small E(9)$ expected number of $ \small HH$ in $ \small 9$ tosses. Now when we have $ \small 10$th toss, we get either $H$ or $T$ with probability $\displaystyle \small \frac{1}{2}$.

i) if $10$th toss is $ \small T$, then $ \small E(10) = E(9)$

ii) if it is $ \small H$, then we have two subcases, each with probability $ \displaystyle \small \frac{1}{2}$ again

- if the string of $ \small 9$ tosses ends with $ \small T$, then $ \small E(10) = E(9)$
- if the string of $\small 9$ tosses ends with $ \small H$, then $ \small E(10) = E(9) + 1$

So combining we have,

$ \displaystyle \small E(10) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot E(9) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \big[ \frac{1}{2} \cdot E(9) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (E(9) + 1) \big] = E(9) + \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: The doubt I have is precisely this. When we are considering case (ii), when the string of 9 tosses ends with T, then shouldn't E(10) = E(8) and not E(9) because we are already considering that the 9th toss is a T, so E(9) which is the expected number of HH in first 9 tosses is not the correct representative of E(10)

Comment: But then $E(9)$ is same as $E(8)$ in that specific case, right? If we are going to $E(8)$ when 9th toss is $T$ then what happens if 8th toss was $T$? So by that logic, why would we end at $E(8)$?

Comment: If we write that specific part as $E(8)$, you will have to specifically consider probability of 8th toss being $H$ otherwise you are going to $E(7)$.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is, we have 9 slots for HH.
E(HH) = E(I1) + E(I2) + .... + E(9) => 9*E(1)

Now, E(1) = 1/4

Therefore, E(HH) = 9/4 = 2.25.